# Close lightbox when click outside box

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax

I have js script like above, `#quick-view-close` as close button and `#quick-view-modal` as box, but when I click outside box, the box should close.

```
$('body').append('<div id="quick-view-modal"><div id="quick-view-content">
<div id="quick-view-close"></div><div class="quick-view-content">
<div class="quick-view-container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
</div>
</div>      
</div>
</div>');

$('#quick-view-modal').hide();
    $('#quick-view-close').click(function(){
        $('#quick-view-modal').fadeOut(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#quick-view-modal').length){
        $("#quick-view-modal").fadeOut(300);
    }
});
```